# Adding Swift Closures as values to Swift dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I want to create a Swift dictionary that holds String type as its keys and Closures as its values. Following is the code that I have but it gives me the error:

'@lvalue is not identical to '(String, () -> Void)'

```
class CommandResolver {
     private var commandDict:[String : () -> Void]!

     init() {
         self.setUpCommandDict();
     }

     func setUpCommandDict() {

         self.commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"] = {
                 println("I am inside closure");

          }
      }
  }
```

I tried looking at other question on StackOverflow regarding closures in dictionaries but it does not give me any satisfactory answer. So I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: try `self.commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"]!` ...

Comment: @connor - Its still the same. Also, I am not sure why we need to write self.commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"]!. I am trying to add a closure as the value and key is not optional. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you initialize your dictionary in your `init` before calling your setup function, it should work:

```
class CommandResolver {
    private var commandDict: [String: () -> Void]

    init() {
        commandDict = [:]
        setUpCommandDict()
    }

    func setUpCommandDict() {
        commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"] = {
            println("I am inside closure")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why though? I mean I declare my dictionary as forcefully unwrapped optional so it should be nil by default and even if I initialize it inside setUpcommadDict(), it does not work. I have to initialize it either during declaration or init(). Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Errors like '@lvalue is not identical to '(String, () -> Void)' seem to often be issues with optionals. An implicitly unwrapped optional is still an optional so self.commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"] is also an optional. There may be other ways to get around this but I can't test any at the moment

Comment: I am not sure if the value stored inside of an optional dictionary is optional as well (its not declared optional). Anyways as this solution works, I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the way to go. I am not sure exactly why your implementation does not work though.

```
class CommandResolver {

    typealias MyBlock = () -> Void

    private var commandDict:[String : MyBlock] = [String:MyBlock]()

    init() {
        self.setUpCommandDict();
    }

    func setUpCommandDict() {


        self.commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"] = {
            print("I am inside closure");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works even with Swift 2.x and Xcode 7.x. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Anyone try this in Swift 3?

Comment: Hi this should work fine with Swift 3. Did you have any issue with this ?