# Closures in dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, closures

There's a question already posted with an accepted answer but as of today it's not working. It's throwing an error in Playground `Expected',' separator`

[image: Error]

[Adding Swift Closures as values to Swift dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068114/adding-swift-closures-as-values-to-swift-dictionary)

```
class CommandResolver {
    private var commandDict: [String: () -> Void]

    init() {
        commandDict = [String: () -> Void]()
        setUpCommandDict()
    }

    func setUpCommandDict() {
        commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"] = {
            println("I am inside closure")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a most likely a bug in the compiler. However, there is no need to respecify the type when creating the empty dictionary. Instead, you can just use an empty dictionary literal:

```
init() {
    self.commandDict = [:]
    self.setUpCommandDict()
}
```

The type for the dictionary is inferred from the `commandDict` declaration.

The other solution I have used in the past is to use a `typealias`:

```
class CommandResolver {
    typealias CallbackType = () -> Void
    private var commandDict: [String: CallbackType]

    init() {
        self.commandDict = [String: CallbackType]()
        self.setUpCommandDict()
    }

    func setUpCommandDict() {
        self.commandDict["OpenAssessment_1"] = {
            println("I am inside closure")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this fixes it. I'd have hoped bugs like this would be gone by now.

Comment: Yeah it’s a compiler bug with the [Type]() syntax, simpler case is `let x = [()->()]()` which has the same problem.  However, you can just do self.commandDict = [:] rather than go to the trouble of defining a typealias.